# how to make python program executable in rpi

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, python-2.x

I have a python code which works well in raspberry on boot. I need to hide the code and make the user to non editable. The program have a kivy ingerface and the program starts on start up. Even though the code can be copied by using partitionguru or by other means.Is there any way to protect my code?

Comment: I am not aware of any method of copy protecting Python code.  This is not a Pi specific question.

Comment: Python can be compiled to byte code, which would largely (but not completely) address your issue.  I agree that this is not Pi-specific.  You will probably find answers else where.  Here's something tangentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471191/why-compile-python-code

Comment: Do you need to make it not editable, or not copyable, or both? The question seems to lump them both together.